# Plotting dates by weekdays and groups

Tags: ggplot2, lubridate

I would like to compare the values from different weeks in different groups. Something like daily sales for two team members by week to demonstrate the effect of one person being off/a holiday etc. The time of the sale within each day needs to be ordered within the day but the x axis should be labeled by day.
Example is arbitrary.

Example data and output

```
stringsAsFactors =FALSE
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#=======================
# Week on week comparison of days by a group
#=======================
# Generate DF
Date <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-04-01"),as.Date("2020-04-14"),by="days"),4))
Time <- data.frame(Time = c(rep("00:00:01",nrow(Date)/2),rep("00:00:02",nrow(Date)/2)))
Type <- data.frame(Type = rep(c(rep("a",nrow(Date)/4),rep("b",nrow(Date)/4)),2))
df <- cbind(Date,Time,Type)

# Add random values to plot
df %<>% mutate(values = runif(nrow(.),1,10))

# Create a groups for weeks, orders for days and labels as weekdays (char strings).
df %<>% mutate(weekLevel = week(Date), 
               dayLevel = wday(Date), 
               Day = as.character(weekdays(Date)), 
               orderVar = paste0(dayLevel, Time))


ggplot(df %>% arrange(orderVar), aes(x =  orderVar, y = values,group = interaction(Type,weekLevel),colour=Type))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks =df$orderVar , labels = df$Day) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle =  90, hjust=1))
```

This works but the day is repeated because the breaks are set to a more granular level than the labels. It also feels a bit hacky.

Any and all feedback is appreciate :)

Comment: This is a difficult one to answer. If you want the total sales by day to compare you'd need to sum all sales each day, but then you can't show a new point for each sale. Maybe as well giving each person a `facet` to compare more clearly? Can post some potential ways forward if that seems clear?

Comment: Thanks! I don't want an aggregate by day, thanks though. As a background, a friend had a tech test to do in Python and I was wondering how I would do it in R. Faceting in rows (in this case), by week, was the closest I could think of but, IMO, its still harder to read than the output above.